# sampler1d хранит/рисует только степени двойки

Tags: opengl, glsl, текстура

Стоит задача нарисовать 5 (или другое число, не являющееся степенью двойки) точек на экране при помощи текстуры. В шейдер как атрибут приходит массив координат по оси 0Х. По оси 0Y, 0Z нули.

Отрисовка этих точек без использования текстуры происходит корректно. Вот код:

```
// vert x-coord
attribute float a_xcoord;

void main(){
    gl_PointSize = 10;
    gl_Position = vec4(a_xcoord, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Когда вместо массива атрибутов используется одномерная текстура с теми же данными и c параметрами:

```
InternalFormat - R32F
GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER - GL_NEAREST,
GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER - GL_NEAREST
DataFormat - GL_RED
```

количество точек на экране равно степени 2 (1, 2, 4 и.т.д), даже если текстура имела размер, не равный степени двойки. Пример: хотим нарисовать 5 точек, а рисует 4. Вот код:

```
// номер вершины (0, 1, 2 и т.д.)
attribute float a_id;

// текстура с x-компонентами точек
uniform sampler1D u_x;
// размер текстуры
uniform float x_len;

void main(){
    // по номеру точки получаем значение из текстуры
    // + 0.5 - чтобы попасть в середину пикселя
    float x = texture1D(u_x, (a_id + 0.5) / x_len).r;

    gl_PointSize = 10;
    gl_Position = vec4(x, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Параметр `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` такой:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

Большое замечание: второй код работает корректно на видеокарте NVIDIA. Проблема со степенями двойки возникает на карте Intel(R) HD Graphics. Версия драйвера: 8.15.10.2622

Прикладываю код целиком:

```
string vertex_code =
    "#version 120\n"
    "uniform sampler1D u_x;"
    "uniform float x_len;"

    "attribute float position;"
    "void main() "
    "{ "
    "    float x = texture1D(u_x, (position + 0.5) / x_len).r;"
    "    gl_Position = vec4(x / 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); "
    "    gl_PointSize = 10.0;"
"} ";

string fragment_code =
    "#version 120\n"

    "void main() "
    "{ "
    "    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); "
    "} ";

class MyClass {
    GLuint program_id;
    GLint a_position_id;
    GLuint x_tex;
    GLint u_x_id;
    GLint x_len_id;
    GLuint vbo_id;
    int a_pos_len = 0;

    public:
    MyClass() {}

    void on_initialize(){
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        // ------------------- Build & activate program ----------------------
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Request a program and shader slots from GPU
        program_id = glCreateProgram();
        GLuint vertex_id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        GLuint fragment_id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        // Set shaders source
        glShaderSource(vertex_id, vertex_code);
        glShaderSource(fragment_id, fragment_code);

        // Compile vertex shader
        glCompileShader(vertex_id);
        GLint compile_ok = glGetShader1i(vertex_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS);
        if (!compile_ok){
            std::string log = glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_id);
            glDeleteShader(vertex_id);
            throw GlException("Error in vertex shader compiling: " + log);
        }

        // Compile fragment shader
        glCompileShader(fragment_id);
        compile_ok = glGetShader1i(fragment_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS);
        if (!compile_ok){
            std::string log = glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_id);
            glDeleteShader(fragment_id);
            throw GlException("Error in fragment shader compiling: " + log);
        }

        // Attach shader objects to the program
        glAttachShader(program_id, vertex_id);
        glAttachShader(program_id, fragment_id);

        // Build program
        glLinkProgram(program_id);
        GLint link_ok = glGetProgram1i(program_id, GL_LINK_STATUS);
        if (!link_ok){
            std::string log = glGetProgramInfoLog(program_id);
            throw GlException("Error in program linking: " + log);
        }


        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        // ------------------------- Create VBO ------------------------------
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Create vbo.
        vbo_id = glCreateBuffer();
        // make this buffer default.
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id);
        GLfloat a_pos[] = {
           0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
        };
        a_pos_len = 5;
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(a_pos), a_pos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        // ------------------------- Create Texture --------------------------
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------

        glGenTextures(1, &x_tex);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, x_tex);

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        glTexImage1D(
                GL_TEXTURE_1D,
                0,
                GL_R32F,
                a_pos_len,
                0,
                GL_RED,
                GL_FLOAT,
                a_pos
             );

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0);

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        // ------------------------- Set Uniforms ----------------------------
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------

        x_len_id = glGetUniformLocation(program_id, "x_len");
        if (x_len_id == -1)
            throw GlException("Could not bind uniforms");

        glUseProgram(program_id);

        glUniform1f(x_len_id, a_pos_len);

        glUseProgram(0);
    }

    void on_paint() {
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        // ------------------- Bind VBO to attribute -------------------------
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Get attribute location.
        a_position_id = glGetAttribLocation(program_id, "position");
        if (a_position_id == -1)
            throw GlException("Could not bind attributes");


        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_id);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            a_position_id,     // attribute
            1,                 // number of elements per vertex
            GL_FLOAT,          // the type of each element
            GL_FALSE,          // take our values as-is
            0,                 // no extra data between each position
            0                  // offset of first element
        );

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        // ------------------------ Draw arrays ------------------------------
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------

        // clear screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Enable alpha.
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        // Use glsl program.
        glUseProgram(program_id);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, x_tex);

        /* Push each element in buffer_vertices to the vertex shader */
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_position_id);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, a_pos_len);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(a_position_id);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0);

        glUseProgram(0);
    }

    void on_delete() {
        // free resources
        glDeleteProgram(program_id);
        glDeleteBuffer(vbo_id);
    }
};
```

Приведенная программа рисует 4 точки вместо 5.

Comment: Попробуйте проверить наличия этого экстеншена: https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_non_power_of_two.txt Скорее всего он не поддерживается вашей Intel(R) HD Graphics.

Comment: Уточните что значит "хотим нарисовать 5 точек, а рисует 4" ? Возможно, что Intel(R) HD Graphics криво обрабатывает NPOT текстуры, и 5-я точка сэмплится из пустого, которое дополняет NPOT до POT размера.

Comment: @Unick проверила, данное расширение поддерживается. Причем тот же шейдер в vispy отлично рисуется не со степенями двойки. А в Qt-проекте нет. Может быть, надо использовать какие-нибудь glEnable?

Comment: @Kromster если количество точек не степень двойки, то программа округляет в меньшую сторону до ближайшей степени двойки. 5,6,7 - до 4. 15, 14, ..., 9 - до 8.

Comment: @Helen подробно не гуглил, но пишут, что поддержка Vertex Texture Fetch (сэмплинг из текстур в вертексном шейдере) появилась далеко не сразу и не у всех производителей. Возможно на вашей Intel HD она на работает должным образом. Попробуйте обновить драйвера или погуглить как проверить наличие/полноту поддержки VTF.

Comment: @Helen Как вы рисуете точки? Ресуете прямоугольник, который при отрисовки должен занять 4 точки, или рисуете отдельные точки? Можете привести код, подготови к отрисовки и вызов отрисовки?

Comment: Также приложите вашу текстуру к вопросы и скриншот результата работы программы

Comment: @Unick Приложу код, можно сказать, целиком. Постаралась выделить ключевые блоки комментариями. Если что-то непонятно,  поясню.

Comment: А результат: 4 красные точки вместо 5.

Comment: Проверяли ли вы присутсвие каких-либо ошибок OpenGL функцией glGetError? Также попробуйте использовать GL_RED вместо GL_R32F.